# Adjoint of an Operator in $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $l^2$ be the Hilbert space of all complex sequences $\phi =(\phi_j)_{j=0}^{\infty}$ such that  $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} |\phi_j |^2 < \infty$. Set

$D= \{ \phi \in l^2 : \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} j |\phi_j |^2 < \infty \}$,

and consider the operator $X$ on $D$ which associates to each $\phi \in D$ the vector $X \phi$, whose j-th component (j=0,1,2,...) is

$(X \phi)_j = \sqrt{j+1} \psi_{j+1} + \sqrt{j} \psi_{j-1}$,

(we set $\psi_{-1}=0$). We have for every $\phi \in l^2 , \psi \in D$ 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \bar{\phi_j} [\sqrt{j+1} \psi_{j+1} + \sqrt{j} \psi_{j-1}] = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_j \overline{ [\sqrt{j+1} \phi_{j+1} + \sqrt{j} \phi_{j-1}]},
\end{equation}
where again we set $\phi_{-1}=0$.
So in particular, $X$ is a symmetric operator. But it is not self-adjoint. To see this, consider the vector $\phi$ whose j-th component is $\phi_j = (-1)^{\lfloor j/2 \rfloor} j^{-\beta}$, where $1/2 < \beta <1$. Is is easy to see that $\phi \in l^2 \backslash D$, and that the vector whose j-th component  is $\sqrt{j+1} \phi_{j+1} + \sqrt{j} \phi_{j-1}$ is in $l^2$, so $\phi$ belongs to the domain of the adjoint. I conjectured that the domain of the adjoint $X^{*}$ is exactly the set of all vectors $\phi \in l^2$ such that $ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}  |\sqrt{j+1} \phi_{j+1} + \sqrt{j} \phi_{j-1} |^2 < \infty$. Anyhow, I could not prove it, and now I am starting to think that it is false. See also my related post "Null functional on $l^2$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed domain for the adjoint $X^\star$ appears to me to be correct.

As defined,
$$
      (Xf,g) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(\sqrt{j+1}f_{j+1}+\sqrt{j}f_{j-1})\overline{g_j}.
$$
By definition of adjoint, $g\in\mathcal{D}(X^{\star})$ iff there exists $h \in \ell^2$ such that the following holds for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(X)$:
$$
               \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(\sqrt{j+1}f_{j+1}+\sqrt{j}f_{j-1})\overline{g_j}=(Xf,g) = (f,h) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}f_j\overline{h_j}
$$
In particular, it must hold for $f=(0,1,0,0,\cdots)$, which leads to
$$
                      \overline{g_0}+\sqrt{2}\overline{g_2}=\overline{h_1} \implies h_1=g_0+\sqrt{2}g_2.
$$
And it must hold for $f=(0,0,1,0,\cdots)$, which gives
$$
                      \sqrt{2}\overline{g_1}+\sqrt{3}\overline{g_3}=\overline{h_2} \implies h_2= \sqrt{2}g_1+\sqrt{3}g_3
$$
So it is necessary that $h_j=\sqrt{j}g_{j-1}+\sqrt{j+1}g_{j+1}$. And it is necessary that $\sum_{j}|h_j|^2 < \infty$. So $g$ is in your proposed domain $\mathscr{D}$. Conversely, suppose $g\in\mathscr{D}$, and suppose $f \in \mathcal{D}(X)$. Then
$$
         \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(\sqrt{j+1}f_{j+1}+\sqrt{j}f_{j-1})\overline{g_j}
          -\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}f_j(\sqrt{j+1}\overline{g_j}+\sqrt{j}\overline{g_{j-1}}) = 0,
$$
because you can rearrange the terms in the first sum without affecting convergence in order to match the terms in the second sum. (This is because $f\in\mathcal{D}(X)$ implies the absolute convergence of $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{j+1}f_{j+1}\overline{g_{j}}$ and of $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{j}f_{j-1}\overline{g_{j}}$.)

Comment: For sure, your argument is correct, and I thank you very much for having clearly answered my question. Still I have a big doubt about this operator. Is the closure of $X$ equal to the adjoint $X^{*}$? Clearly, the domain of $\bar{X}$  is contained in the domain $D$ of $X^{*}$, but I can't show the reverse inclusion. Any help is welcome.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : Have you tried to solve $X^\star f= \pm i f$? If either has a non-trivial solution with $f \in \ell^2$, then $X$ cannot be essentially selfadjoint, meaning that the closure of $X$ is not $X^{\star}$. That actually resolves the problem one way or the other. I don't have much time at the moment, or I would try.

Comment: I checked that the equation $X^{*}f= \pm i f$ has only the trivial solution, but I didn't understand why this should imply that the closure of $X$ is strictly contained in the adjoint $X^{*}$ of $X$. Could you give me some hint or some reference where I could learn this fact, please? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I have found the result you were referring to in Schmudgen, Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space, Proposition 3.8. Thank you very much for your invaluable help. I wouldn't be able to answer these questions by myself!

Comment: @MauryBarbato : You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help. Knowing that $\mathcal{N}(X^{\star}\pm iI)=\{0\}$ means that $X^{\star}$ must be the closure of $X$ because $\mathcal{D}(X^{\star})=\mathcal{D}(X^c)\oplus\mathcal{N}(X^{\star}-iI)\oplus \mathcal{N}(X^{\star}+iI)$, where $X^c$ is the closure of a densely-defined symmetric operator. These null spaces are the deficiency spaces.

Comment: @MauryBarbato : You get solutions of the equations for $X^{\star}f=\pm if$, but I could not tell off hand if the solutions were in $\ell^2$. Knowing there are no non-zero solutions then gives $X^c = X^{\star}$, which is the definition of $X$ being essentially selfadjoint because the closure $X^c$ must be selfadjoint when the deficiency spaces are trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! Only I have some doubt about your statement that e.g. $X^{\star} f = if$ has some non-trivial solution. Actually, I wrote down this equation componentwise, starting from the 0-th component and it has only the zero vector solution (the equations for the first two components give $f_{0}=f_{1}=0$, the third then gives $f_{2}=0$, and so on). What did you mean when you said it has some other solution maybe not in $\ell^2$? Thank you very much again!

Comment: @MauryBarbato : The first equation is $\sqrt{0+1}f_{0+1}=if_{0}$, which leaves $f_{0}$ arbitrary, and $f_{1}=if_{0}$. The next equation is $\sqrt{2}f_{2}+\sqrt{1}f_{0}=if_{1}$, which gives $f_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \{ if_{1}-f_{0} \}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (i-1)f_{0}$, etc.. So all terms are expressed in terms of the arbitrary $f_{0}$. The only issue is whether or not the resulting $\{ f_n \}$ is in $\ell^2$.

Comment: Ops, you're right. I made a trivial mistake in writing down the equations. Now I see your point. It's not a trivial task to check whether the sequence $f$ recursively defined is in $\ell^{2}$!

Comment: As I pointed out in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1644775/252672) to Maury's other question, these tri-diagonal symmetric operators are equivalent to Jacobi matrices. They are essentially self-adjoint if the off-diagonal elements grow no faster than n (roughly speaking) (this can be used to prove Nelson's analytic vector theorem). There are Jacobi matrices which are not essentially self-adjoint, so any proof that works in general is suspect.

Comment: Let $S$ be the linear subspace of all vectors in $\ell^2$ with only finitely many non-zero coordinates. By the result Keith quoted about Jacobi operators (see also Schmudgen, Unbounded Self-Adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space, Example 7.6), the restriction $P$ of $X$ to $S$ is essentially self-adjoint. So we have $P^{*}= \bar{P}=\bar{X}$. But since $(\bar{T})^{*}=T^{*}$ for every closable operator defined on a dense linear subspace, we get ${X}^{*}=(\bar{X})^{*}=(\bar{P})^{*}=P^{*}=\bar{X}$. So $X$ is essentially self-adjoint.

Answer (score 1):

It occurred to me that your problem has to do with a creation and
annihilation operator, according to
\begin{eqnarray*}
X &=&U+V \\
a^{\ast } &=&V,\;a=U
\end{eqnarray*}
see below.

Let $\mathcal{H}=l^{2}$ \ with elements $u=u_{1},u_{2},\cdots $ and
let $K$ be defined by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{D}(K) &=&\mathcal{D},\;\mathcal{D}=\{u\in l^{2}|\sum_{j=0}^{\infty
}j|u_{j}|^{2}<\infty \} \\
(Ku)_{j} &=&\sqrt{j}u_{j},\;u\in \mathcal{D}
\end{eqnarray*}
$K$ is symmetric, non-negative on $\mathcal{D}$ and its null space consists
of the elements $(u_{0},0,0,\cdots )$. In fact it is self-adjoint on $%
\mathcal{D}$ according to
\begin{eqnarray*}
(Ku,v) &=&(u,f) \\
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }\sqrt{j}u_{j}\bar{v}_{j} &=&\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }\sqrt{j}%
u_{j}\bar{v}_{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }u_{j}\bar{f}_{j}\Rightarrow f_{j}=\sqrt{%
j}\bar{v}_{j},\;j\neq 0 \\
j &=&0\Rightarrow 0=(u_{0},f_{0})\Rightarrow f_{0}=0
\end{eqnarray*}
We introduce the scale of spaces
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{H}_{k}=[K+i]^{-k}\mathcal{H}
\end{equation*}
As a set $\mathcal{H}_{k}$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ and is itself a Hilbert
space under the norm (or an equivalent one)
\begin{equation*}
\parallel f\parallel _{k}=\parallel Kf\parallel _{\mathcal{H}},\;f\in
\mathcal{H}_{k}.
\end{equation*}
Thus $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_{0}$, $\mathcal{D=H}_{1}$. For $u\in \mathcal{D%
}$ the operator $X$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
(Xu)_{j} &=&\sqrt{j+1}u_{j+1}+\sqrt{j}u_{j-1}=(Uu)_{j}+(Vu)_{j},\;j>0,
\;(Xu)_{j}=u_{1} \\
(Uu)_{j} &=&\sqrt{j+1}u_{j+1},\;(Vu)_{j}=\sqrt{j}u_{j-1},\;j>0,
\;(Uu)_{0}=u_{1},\;(Vu)_{0}=0
\end{eqnarray*}
$X$, $U$ and $V$ are bounded operators from $\mathcal{H}_{1}$ onto $\mathcal{
H}$. Next we note that $V=U^{\ast }.$ We note that for $u,v\in \mathcal{D}$
\begin{equation*}
(Uu,v)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }\sqrt{j+1}u_{j+1}\bar{v}_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty
}u_{j}\sqrt{j}\bar{v}_{j-1}=(u,Vv)
\end{equation*}
so $U^{\ast }\subset V$. Let now
\begin{eqnarray*}
(Uu,f) &=&(u,g) \\
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }\sqrt{j+1}u_{j+1}\bar{f}_{j} &=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }u_{j}
\bar{g}_{j} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty }u_{j}\sqrt{j}\bar{f}_{j-1} &=&\sum_{j=0}^{\infty }u_{j}
\bar{g}_{j}
\end{eqnarray*}
Choosing a specific $u$ we find
\begin{eqnarray*}
g_{0} &=&0 \\
g_{j} &=&\sqrt{j}\bar{f}_{j-1},\;j>0
\end{eqnarray*}
so $U^{\ast }=V$.
For $u\in \mathcal{H}_{2}=[K+i]^{-2}\mathcal{H}$, denoting $u=[K+i]^{-2}f$
\begin{eqnarray*}
(U^{\ast }Uu)_{j} &=&(U^{\ast }U[K+i]^{-2}f)_{j}=\sqrt{j}
(U[K+i]^{-2}f)_{j-1}=j([K+i]^{-2}f)_{j}=(K^{2}[K+i]^{-2}f)_{j},\;j\neq 0 \\
(U^{\ast }Uu)_{0} &=&0=(K^{2}[K+i]^{-2}f)_{0} \\
(UU^{\ast }u)_{j} &=&(UU^{\ast }[K+i]^{-2}f)_{j}=\sqrt{j+1}(U^{\ast
}[K+i]^{-2}f)_{j+1}=(j+1)([K+i]^{-2}f)_{j}=((K^{2}+1)[K+i]^{-2}f)_{j} \\
(UU^{\ast }\varphi )_{0} &=&(UU^{\ast }[K+i]^{-2}f)_{0}=(U^{\ast
}[K+i]^{-2}f)_{1}=([K+i]^{-2}f)_{0}\neq 0 \\
\{UU^{\ast }-U^{\ast }U\}\varphi  &=&\{UU^{\ast }-U^{\ast
}U\}[K+i]^{-2}f=[K+i]^{-2}f \\
UU^{\ast }-U^{\ast }U &=&[U,U^{\ast }]==1\;\mathrm{on}\;\mathcal{H}_{2}\;
\mathrm{extends\;to\;}\mathcal{H}
\end{eqnarray*}
Recall that creation and annihilation operators satisfy
\begin{equation*}
\lbrack a,a^{\ast }]=1
\end{equation*}
so we can identify
\begin{equation*}
a=U,\;a^{\ast }=U^{\ast }=V
\end{equation*}
Then $K^{2}=U^{\ast }U$ is the number operator.